# FullCalendar2 - add href to a tag afte ajax render

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar2 library](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/), and I need to show a custom a tag after ajax post event. Is this possible?

This is my code so far:

```
$('#mainModal').off('submit', '#calendar-form').on('submit', '#calendar-form', function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                var $this    = $(this);

                $.post($this.attr('action'), $this.serialize(), function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

                    eventData = {
                        title: $this.find('input[role=title]').val(),
                        start: $this.find('input[role=date]').val(),
                        id: data.id
                    };

                    $('#w0').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);

                    $('#w0').fullCalendar('unselect');

                    mainModal.modal('hide');
                });

            });
```